# Best Way to store Application Configuration for Windows Store App

Tags: xml, configuration, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I've been reading on methods for WP7, but have yet to see any real writeup on what to do for a Windows 8 App.

So, if I want to store settings.  Some are text fields about the user that they enter, some configuration check boxes and say, color preference.  What's the best or more importantly, proper way to do this.

In VS2012 for a windows application, you can add an application configuration file to the project, but this seems missing for a windows store app project/solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Runtime exposes LocalSettings, RoamingSettings which can be used to store app related settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx

you can use this to create / store app specific config.

Alternative route is to have a xml file while stores you config. You can parse the xml on app load and exposes the properties of custom config class

I personally create a Config class which exposes static properties. The static properties read / write to Local / Roaming Settings.